# Prevent terminal tabs from auto-renaming

Tags: terminal, bash, ssh, tabs

I like to name my tabs when I'm using Terminal so I can keep track of what's inside of them. I do this using the inspector.

Unfortunately, whenever I ssh into a machine, my tabs get renamed. Is there any way to prevent this from happening? Perhaps there's some kind of shell script I could run in my bash profile to prevent this?

Answer (score 6):

Using iTerm2 you actually have an option for that:
Just uncheck *Preferences->Profiles->`Your Profile`->Terminal->Terminal may set tab/window title*.
[image: Fancy description]

Comment: It's been moved to `Preferences` ➡ `Profiles` ➡ `[your profile]` ➡ `General` ➡ `Applications in terminal may change the title`

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a new or change an existing profile in the settings of `Terminal`.

Choose your new or the existing profile and click on `Window` and uncheck all the options at the `Title` segment.

Edit:
For shells which change the promt via shell variable `PS1` you have to deal with it as long you connected the the given host without changing the promt on the remote session.
To change this in a bash you will find something like

```
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\H: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

in your `.bashrc`.

If you comment out this block your local title will not change but your promt may be looking awful.

Maybe there are other lines where the shell variable `PS1` is set. Maybe you have to comment out these too.

Edit2:
Also you have the ability to give the local `PS1` to the remote session.
To do so you invoke `ssh` with

```
ssh -o SendEnv=PS1 user@host
```

But for this you have to edit the `sshd_config`.
There you have to add `PS1` to the list of `AcceptEnv`.
This requires root access. Maybe not really a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to never rename your window, no matter where you connect from, you might want to change the setting in the remote machine. The thing that renames the window is the escape sequence \033k, as described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Title-Prompts.html)

> Bash users will probably want to echo the escape sequence in the
>   PROMPT_COMMAND:
>
> ```
> PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033k\033\134"'
> ```

In this case, if you change the `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable in your remote shell, it will stop renaming the window.